# How to reference dependencies in license documentation

Tags: java, maven

I'm working on a commercial project which uses many open source libraries as its foundation. It's a Java project and we use maven to resolve dependencies. This is great but ... the companies to whom we want to sell our software are traditionally conservative about what they allow to run on site and will want a full inventory of all third party libraries used. Now I can get the list by looking at our project's pom files to find our first order dependencies and then I suppose use the magic of maven to trace all the transitive dependencies. It will be a long list however and one which is likely to change as we move from version to version of any of the third party packages.

Is there an established approach to documenting this kind of dependency tree?

Is there an accepted "lawyer friendly" form of describing software dependencies that I should be adopting?

Any suggestions would be most welcome!

Cheers

Rich

Comment: I would suggest to take a look at the [license-maven-plugin](http://www.mojohaus.org/license-maven-plugin/) which can produce a list of all dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-project-info-reports-plugin/license-mojo.html 
(a part of http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-project-info-reports-plugin/_ )

and

Use **license-check-maven-plugin**

```
<build>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.complykit</groupId>
      <artifactId>license-check-maven-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>0.5.3</version>
      <executions>
        <execution>
          <phase>verify</phase>
          <goals>
            <goal>os-check</goal>
          </goals>
        </execution>
      </executions>
    </plugin>
  </plugins>
</build>
```

Reference: https://github.com/mrice/license-check